# Elementwise comparison of numpy arrays of different lengths

Tags: python, numpy, comparison, elementwise-operations

This seems like a simple thing to do but I could not figure it out...

```
first = np.array([0,1,2,0,4,2])
second = np.array([1,2])
```

I'd like to do element-wise comparison so that the answer will be

```
array([False, True, True, False, False, True], dtype=bool)
```

Basically I want it to say `True` for each of the elements in `first` which is also in `second`. So if `first` has 100 elements, then the output should have 100 elements, too.
But I can't figure out how. I've tried using `np.equal`, `np.any`, `first==np.any(second)` to no avail. Of course, I can write a loop to do this but I know there must be a way to do this relatively simple task!

Comment: What's the rule that's supposed to give those results? Do you want to repeat the shorter one in a loop or something? And what comparison are you doing between the elements? I can't think of what would make `0 ??? 1` be False but `1 ??? 2` be True.

Comment: Basically I want it to say True if each of the element in first is in second. So if first has 100 elements, then the output should have 100 elements, too. I've updated the question to clarify this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are asking for is what [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) does:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> first = np.array([0,1,2,0,4,2])
>>> second = np.array([1,2])
>>> np.isin(first, second)
array([False,  True,  True, False, False,  True])
```

Comment: YES! I did not know there is `np.isin`. I've only used in the built-in function `in` for python. thank you so much!

Comment: @puifais it's fairly new, added in version `1.13.0`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is a cartesian product operation—compare every element of `first` to every element of `second`. You can do this by lifting `second` to a 2D array, so you get back a 2D result:

```
>>> first == second.reshape(2,1)
array([[False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False,  True]])
```

And then you apparently want to flatten that into a single row by running `np.any`. You can do that by passing an `axis` argument:

```
>>> (first == second.reshape(2,1)).any(axis=0)
array([False,  True,  True, False, False,  True])
```

That matches your desired output, so I think it's what you were asking for?

But of course this takes `O(N*M)` space (6x2 in your example). That's generally the way of numpy—if you want to do things as fast as possible, you need to build an array big enough to hold all the results at each step. In this case, because you're doing a cartesian product in a single step, that's a 6x2 array.

But quite often, that isn't actually what you want. If you just want to do a `in`-type search for each value in `first` against each value in `second`, just use the `isin` function, which will do the same work *without* ever building a 6x2 array. And it's simpler than what you were trying to write, too.